# DDMathParser - Using a string as an argument in a custom function

Tags: objective-c, ddmathparser

I would like to make a function which would allow me to pass a string in the argument - what's the best way to do this?

eg..
Moles("Ca(OH)2")

Any help would be extremely gratefully received.

Comment: I responded to the issue you filed on github: https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/issues/42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting this in by parsing strings as variables.  So for DDMathParser:

```
someFunction("Hello")
```

... is equivalent to:

```
someFunction($Hello)
```

However, this means you can have variables now with more complex stuff:

```
someFunction("Hello world")
Moles("Ca(OH)2")
```

... etc